# How to get more gpg-agent info?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I followed
[encrypted netrc file with gpg](https://bryanwweber.com/writing/personal/2016/01/01/how-to-set-up-an-encrypted-netrc-file-with-gpg-for-github-2fa-access/)
tutorial.
I edited my

```
~/.profile
```

like this

```
if test -f $HOME/.gpg-agent-info && \
    kill -0 `cut -d: -f 2 $HOME/.gpg-agent-info` 2>/dev/null; then
    GPG_AGENT_INFO=`cat $HOME/.gpg-agent-info | cut -c 16-`
else
    # No, gpg-agent not available; start gpg-agent
    eval `gpg-agent --daemon --no-grab --write-env-file $HOME/.gpg-agent-info`
fi
export GPG_TTY=`tty`
export GPG_AGENT_INFO
```

This is `ls` for `./gnupg`

```
~/.gnupg$ ls
openpgp-revocs.d  private-keys-v1.d  pubring.kbx  pubring.kbx~  random_seed  trustdb.gpg
```

It does not work,when I restart my Ubuntu error pops up that I already have one gpg-agent running. How to check this and fix this?

```
eval `gpg-agent --daemon --no-grab $HOME/.gpg-agent-info`
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one
```

Comment: What are your Ubuntu and gnupg versions? Here (on Arch Linux, not Ubuntu) gpg-agent from gnupg 2.2.23 says that _"--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect_

Comment: Could you maybe just use `gpgconf --kill all` first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That tutorial is obsolete, and all you should add to your `~/.profile` now is `GPG_TTY=$(tty)`.

On a modern Ubuntu system, the GPG agent sockets are in `/run/user/$UID/gnupg` and systemd will start `gpg-agent` for you automatically when `gpg` runs and tries to access the agent socket.

To confirm this, `gpgconf --list-dirs agent-socket` will show you the path that it's using for the socket, and `systemctl --user status gpg-agent` should show the status of the already-running agent.